# Google Sheets: summarise monthly data

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet with two columns:

1. A date in the form dd/mm/yy
2. The number of people who have registered that day

I have a second sheet in the same workbook also with two columns:

1. The month in the form of mmmm yy
2. The number of people who have registered that month

How do I use SUMIF, without creating additional columns, to fill in the monthly column?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to create a pivot table

[image]

#### Reference:

- [Create and edit pivot tables](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308944?hl=en)